# Retrieving old forms in Contact Form 7

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I recently was having trouble with some of my Contact Form 7 forms so I decided to install the latest version. I backed up (or thought I did) the old version by copying the old Contact Form 7 folder to my computer. Long story short, I had issues with the new version and have chosen to go back to the old. Unfortunately, now that I've copied my backup directory to the WP folder, the plugin works but only one of my old forms is still in the settings menu.

Does anyone know where I can find the rest of the forms I had created? I'm really hoping they're stored somewhere in the directory I copied. Thanks.

Comment: That depends on what the plugin saved to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact Form 7 saves forms and data to the database and not in a directory, except for cahced images like captchas.

Revert the database to recover old forms.

Updating the plugin may irrevocably update the form data, too, so that may be why the forms disappeared.

Comment: The form data of `Contact Form 7` is stored in wp_posts table under `wpcf7_contact_form` post_type.